# problema método hayDosSillasVaciasMismaUbicacion()

Tags: java

buen día compañeros tengo el siguiente problema con el siguiente método:

me aparece el siguiente error:

(Debería retornar false, no hay dos sillas vacías en la misma ubicación en ninguna de las clases 
En el método esta comparando una silla consigo misma, de forma que siempre retornara true mientras haya al menos una silla libre)

/**
     * Indica si hay dos sillas vacías con la misma ubicación en el avión, *Solo se comparan sillas de la misma clase
     * @return - True si hay dos vacías con la misma ubicación, false de lo *contrario
     */

```
public boolean hayDosSillasVaciasMismaUbicacion()
{
    boolean existe = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < SILLAS_EJECUTIVAS && !existe; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < SILLAS_EJECUTIVAS && !existe; j++){
            if(sillasEjecutivas[i].darNumero() != sillasEjecutivas[j].darNumero()){
               if(sillasEjecutivas[i].darUbicacion() == sillasEjecutivas[j].darUbicacion()){
                  return existe = true;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < SILLAS_ECONOMICAS && !existe; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < SILLAS_ECONOMICAS && !existe; j++){
            if(sillasEconomicas[i].darNumero() != sillasEconomicas[j].darNumero()){
               if(sillasEconomicas[i].darUbicacion() == sillasEconomicas[j].darUbicacion()){
                  return existe = true;
               }
            }
        }
    }
       return existe;         

}
```

Hace días estoy con este problema en una herramienta llamada cupitips de un curso de java que estoy haciendo.

Este es el diagrama de clases:
https://cupiexamenes.virtual.uniandes.edu.co/media/web/modelos-mundo/15b1c8ed617.jpg

Enunciado del ejercicio:

Implemente el método hayDosSillasVaciasMismaUbicacion, que indica si existen dos sillas vacías con la misma ubicación (la ubicación corresponde a Ventana, Central o Pasillo). Tenga en cuenta que las sillas deben ser de la misma clase (Económica o Ejecutiva) para que sea válido compararlas.

Comment: Jhon, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Dónde y cómo están almacenadas las sillas? ¿En tu curso te permitirían el uso de la  API `Stream`? Con ella puedes preguntar a tu grupo de sillas si hay más de dos sillas vacías con la misma ubicación de una manera fácil y rápida. Pero eso depende del alcance de tu curso. De todos modos, le falta claridad a tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Deberías proporcionar el código completo ya que faltan piezas importantes como por ejemplo saber de donde viene la constante SILLAS_EJECUTIVAS

Comment: Si es verdad que pena falta información como podría compartir el diagrama de clases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el diagrama de clases, la clase `Silla` tiene el método  `sillaAsignada()`. Pero no lo estás usando.

En el método `hayDosSillasVaciasMismaUbicacion()` sólo estás verificando que hayan 2 sillas de una misma clase en una misma ubicación, pero no que *esten* vacías.

Comment: Eso era lo que me faltaba compañero gracias por tu ayuda.